# MQL5 return and fetch a struct result from function

Tags: mql4, mql5

I do my first steps in MQL5.

I tried to use a function, which should return a struct object (like an array with multiple datatypes of variables).

At the end I want to work with this result. So let me show what I mean.

```
    my_function(){
    
       struct resultdata { string name; double price; int qty; };
       MyData arr[] = {
          {"product 1", 110.000, 200},
          {"product 2", 110.100, 300},
          {"product 3", 110.200, 400},
       };
    }
    
    my_function_feedback=my_function();
    
Print("First is",my_function_feedback[0].name);
```

This way won't work. What did I do wrong or how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't think it is possible to get an mql5 function to return a struct. The closest thing I have figured out how to do is to pass an argument address in the arguments of the function. For example:

```
struct Candle {
    double open;
    double high;
    double low;
    double close;
};

void loadCandle(Candle &candle) {
    candle.open = 12.0;
    candle.high = 12.0;
    candle.low = 12.0;
    candle.close = 12.0;
}
```

To use this function you supply a structure argument and the structure is changed by the function:

```
   Candle c;
   loadCandle(c);
```

I know its not quite the same, but its the closest way that I know about and this question has sat for 7 months with no other answer.

Comment: According to documentation, you can't return any arrays, class objects, variables of compound structure type.
https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/basis/operators/return